# Constraints are not working when changing view orientation

Tags: ios, swift3, orientation, landscape

**How to force update constraints to position view correctly**

My app supports only Portrait orientation, but one view controller should always open in landscape mode. I managed to change orientation forcefully and working properly.

But my view constraints are not working properly when navigating to that view for the very first time or navigate after changing orientation of device. Once it loaded and no orientation change happen its view loaded as expected. Constraints are not framing sub view properly in orientation changed when device is already in that orientation. I am working in xcode 8.2.1.

I checked many links but didn't find any solution for this problem. I tried to update view and constraints also.

```
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.view.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
```

Code I am using is -

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
       let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool
    {
        return true
    }
```

View loaded as this when my device is in already in landscape mode and i navigate to this view controller and force for landscape mode. It updated to landscape mode but don't update constraints.

[image]

When press back and again select the option it shows as it should be in landscape mode.

[image]